# H2 database write access reqd

Tags: h2, talend

I installed Talend Open Studio for MDM and Master data gets stored in H2 Database(which is the only DB provided by product). I created an entity in MDM. But I need to make changes in that entity datatype. I need to drop the entity which I already created. When I am trying to do this, I am getting below error.

```
sa@TMDM_DB/PUBLIC> drop table contact;
```

An error occurred when executing the SQL command: drop table contact

The database is read only; SQL statement: drop table contact [90097-176] [SQL State=90097, DB Errorcode=90097]

how to make this H2 DB as write mode. I need to have write access.

Comment: Why do you need to write directly to the database? You should do whatever changes you need to make directly in Talend MDM and allow it to make any necessary changes to the underlying database.

Comment: I made a mistake while creating table.I need to drop the table and redeploy it. But I am unable to do so. Please help me how can I drop it physically from MDM database which is H2 here.

Comment: You misunderstand. You shouldn't be doing anything directly to the database, Talend MDM should be handling it just as an ORM or other framework that sits above a database may manage its own schema and data.